# How to center a svg in a div container

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I know this question have been asked multiple times on SO. I tried some of those answers but It didn't worked. What is the best way to center the svg element inside div

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" ></script>

</head>

<body> 

<div  id='canvas'></div>


<script>

  var data = [10, 50, 80];
var r = 300;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(['red', 'blue', 'orange']);

var canvas = d3.select('#canvas').append('svg')    
    .attr('width', 700)
    .attr('height', 600);

var group = canvas.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(300, 300)');

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(200)
    .outerRadius(r);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function (d) {
    return d;
});

var arcs = group.selectAll('.arc')
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'arc');

arcs.append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('fill', function (d) {
    return color(d.data);
});

arcs.append('text')
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
    return 'translate(' + arc.centroid(d) + ')';
})
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('font-size', '1.5em')
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.data;
});

</script>   

</body>



</html>
```

I want to put the donut chart in center

[D3 Donut Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPrzr.png)

Comment: What did you try and how did it not work?

Answer (score 12):

You can add couple of css lines to the SVG element. You can inline it or have it in a separate style sheet. Just make sure it loads.

```
svg{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This will align the SVG to the center of the div.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I don't think it is aligned in center completly. It looks to be shifted a bit towards left

Answer (score 1):

Just add centering style to your div.

```
<div  id='canvas' style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

It will work.