# Unable to center or move social media buttons DIV SVG

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I used Nifty buttons to create the code for some social media icons and put them in my footer.  I've tried everything to align and center them and they will not move.  I am able to get the text I have to center so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  Can somone please help me figure out how to move them to the center or right side of my footer?

Here is the code from nifty buttons

```
<div style="display:flex;flex-wrap:"><a href="https://facebook.com/2803155123090634" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;border:0;width:36px;height:36px;padding:0;margin:3px;color:#cce0d7;"><svg class="niftybutton-facebook" style="display:block;fill:currentColor" data-tag="fac" data-name="Facebook" viewBox="0 0 512 512" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"> 
<path d="M211.9 197.4h-36.7v59.9h36.7V433.1h70.5V256.5h49.2l5.2-59.1h-54.4c0 0 0-22.1 0-33.7 0-13.9 2.8-19.5 16.3-19.5 10.9 0 38.2 0 38.2 0V82.9c0 0-40.2 0-48.8 0 -52.5 0-76.1 23.1-76.1 67.3C211.9 188.8 211.9 197.4 211.9 197.4z"></path>
```

Here is the code for the template part `

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="wrap">

<div style="display:flex;flex-wrap:"><a 

href="https://facebook.com/2803155123090634" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;border:0;width:36px;height:36px;padding:0;margin:3px;color:#cce0d7;"><svg class="niftybutton-facebook" style="display:block;fill:currentColor" data-tag="fac" data-name="Facebook" viewBox="0 0 512 512" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"> 
    <path d="M211.9 197.4h-36.7v59.9h36.7V433.1h70.5V256.5h49.2l5.2-59.1h-54.4c0 0 0-22.1 0-33.7 0-13.9 2.8-19.5 16.3-19.5 10.9 0 38.2 0 38.2 0V82.9c0 0-40.2 0-48.8 0 -52.5 0-76.1 23.1-76.1 67.3C211.9 188.8 211.9 197.4 211.9 197.4z"></path> 
</svg></a><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;border:0;width:36px;height:36px;padding:0;margin:3px;color:#cce0d7;"><svg class="niftybutton-twitter" style="display:block;fill:currentColor" data-tag="twi" data-name="Twitter" viewBox="0 0 512 512" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <path d="M419.6 168.6c-11.7 5.2-24.2 8.7-37.4 10.2 13.4-8.1 23.8-20.8 28.6-36 -12.6 7.5-26.5 12.9-41.3 15.8 -11.9-12.6-28.8-20.6-47.5-20.6 -42 0-72.9 39.2-63.4 79.9 -54.1-2.7-102.1-28.6-134.2-68 -17 29.2-8.8 67.5 20.1 86.9 -10.7-0.3-20.7-3.3-29.5-8.1 -0.7 30.2 20.9 58.4 52.2 64.6 -9.2 2.5-19.2 3.1-29.4 1.1 8.3 25.9 32.3 44.7 60.8 45.2 -27.4 21.4-61.8 31-96.4 27 28.8 18.5 63 29.2 99.8 29.2 120.8 0 189.1-102.1 185-193.6C399.9 193.1 410.9 181.7 419.6 168.6z"></path>
</svg></a><a href="https://instagram.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;border:0;width:36px;height:36px;padding:0;margin:3px;color:#cce0d7;"><svg class="niftybutton-instagram" style="display:block;fill:currentColor" data-tag="ins" data-name="Instagram" viewBox="0 0 512 512" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <path d="M256 109.3c47.8 0 53.4 0.2 72.3 1 17.4 0.8 26.9 3.7 33.2 6.2 8.4 3.2 14.3 7.1 20.6 13.4 6.3 6.3 10.1 12.2 13.4 20.6 2.5 6.3 5.4 15.8 6.2 33.2 0.9 18.9 1 24.5 1 72.3s-0.2 53.4-1 72.3c-0.8 17.4-3.7 26.9-6.2 33.2 -3.2 8.4-7.1 14.3-13.4 20.6 -6.3 6.3-12.2 10.1-20.6 13.4 -6.3 2.5-15.8 5.4-33.2 6.2 -18.9 0.9-24.5 1-72.3 1s-53.4-0.2-72.3-1c-17.4-0.8-26.9-3.7-33.2-6.2 -8.4-3.2-14.3-7.1-20.6-13.4 -6.3-6.3-10.1-12.2-13.4-20.6 -2.5-6.3-5.4-15.8-6.2-33.2 -0.9-18.9-1-24.5-1-72.3s0.2-53.4 1-72.3c0.8-17.4 3.7-26.9 6.2-33.2 3.2-8.4 7.1-14.3 13.4-20.6 6.3-6.3 12.2-10.1 20.6-13.4 6.3-2.5 15.8-5.4 33.2-6.2C202.6 109.5 208.2 109.3 256 109.3M256 77.1c-48.6 0-54.7 0.2-73.8 1.1 -19 0.9-32.1 3.9-43.4 8.3 -11.8 4.6-21.7 10.7-31.7 20.6 -9.9 9.9-16.1 19.9-20.6 31.7 -4.4 11.4-7.4 24.4-8.3 43.4 -0.9 19.1-1.1 25.2-1.1 73.8 0 48.6 0.2 54.7 1.1 73.8 0.9 19 3.9 32.1 8.3 43.4 4.6 11.8 10.7 21.7 20.6 31.7 9.9 9.9 19.9 16.1 31.7 20.6 11.4 4.4 24.4 7.4 43.4 8.3 19.1 0.9 25.2 1.1 73.8 1.1s54.7-0.2 73.8-1.1c19-0.9 32.1-3.9 43.4-8.3 11.8-4.6 21.7-10.7 31.7-20.6 9.9-9.9 16.1-19.9 20.6-31.7 4.4-11.4 7.4-24.4 8.3-43.4 0.9-19.1 1.1-25.2 1.1-73.8s-0.2-54.7-1.1-73.8c-0.9-19-3.9-32.1-8.3-43.4 -4.6-11.8-10.7-21.7-20.6-31.7 -9.9-9.9-19.9-16.1-31.7-20.6 -11.4-4.4-24.4-7.4-43.4-8.3C310.7 77.3 304.6 77.1 256 77.1L256 77.1z"></path>
    <path d="M256 164.1c-50.7 0-91.9 41.1-91.9 91.9s41.1 91.9 91.9 91.9 91.9-41.1 91.9-91.9S306.7 164.1 256 164.1zM256 315.6c-32.9 0-59.6-26.7-59.6-59.6s26.7-59.6 59.6-59.6 59.6 26.7 59.6 59.6S288.9 315.6 256 315.6z"></path>
    <circle cx="351.5" cy="160.5" r="21.5"></circle>
                        </svg></a></div> 


</div><!-- .wrap -->
            </div><!-- .col -->
        </div><!-- .row -->

    </div><!-- .container -->

</div><!-- .site-info-inside -->
```

Here is the code for the footer.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after
 *
 * @package Wisteria
 */
?>

</div><!-- #content -->

<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
    <?php
    // Site Info
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/site-info' );
    ?>
</footer><!-- #colophon -->

</div><!-- #page .site-wrapper -->

<div class="overlay-effect"></div><!-- .overlay-effect -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I've read everything about how to center a div and tried so many different things they will not center properly.

I've tried methods from other posts ["how to center button within a div"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560832/how-to-center-a-button-within-a-div?rq=1) ["Horizontally center a div?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div?rq=1) ["How to center a svg in a div container?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101825/how-to-center-a-svg-in-a-div-container)

Nothing seems to work for me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code for your footer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The theme I am using uses a template part to insert site info in the footer. I've inserted the code for both the footer.php and the template-part

Comment: We don't need the php file - the HTML you provided in the second code block is good. But, please update the second code block with the niffty buttons in it, along with the CSS you've tried.

Comment: Hi thanks, I have updated the second box to have the nifty button code in it.

Comment: @disnfor  I have updated the post with everything I've tried as well. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on reddit was able to solve this for me! I changed the code to this below and it worked like a charm.

```
    <div style="display:flex;align-items: center;width: 100%;justify-content: center;">

<a href="https://facebook.com/2803155123090634" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;border:0;width:36px;height:36px;padding:0;margin:3px;color:#cce0d7;" target="_blank"><svg class="niftybutton-facebook" data-name="Facebook" data-tag="fac" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="display:block;fill:currentColor" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<path d="M211.9 197.4h-36.7v59.9h36.7V433.1h70.5V256.5h49.2l5.2-59.1h-54.4c0 0 0-22.1 0-33.7 0-13.9 2.8-19.5 16.3-19.5 10.9 0 38.2 0 38.2 0V82.9c0 0-40.2 0-48.8 0 -52.5 0-76.1 23.1-76.1 67.3C211.9 188.8 211.9 197.4 211.9 197.4z"></path></svg></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;border:0;width:36px;height:36px;padding:0;margin:3px;color:#cce0d7;" target="_blank"><svg class="niftybutton-twitter" data-name="Twitter" data-tag="twi" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="display:block;fill:currentColor" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<path d="M419.6 168.6c-11.7 5.2-24.2 8.7-37.4 10.2 13.4-8.1 23.8-20.8 28.6-36 -12.6 7.5-26.5 12.9-41.3 15.8 -11.9-12.6-28.8-20.6-47.5-20.6 -42 0-72.9 39.2-63.4 79.9 -54.1-2.7-102.1-28.6-134.2-68 -17 29.2-8.8 67.5 20.1 86.9 -10.7-0.3-20.7-3.3-29.5-8.1 -0.7 30.2 20.9 58.4 52.2 64.6 -9.2 2.5-19.2 3.1-29.4 1.1 8.3 25.9 32.3 44.7 60.8 45.2 -27.4 21.4-61.8 31-96.4 27 28.8 18.5 63 29.2 99.8 29.2 120.8 0 189.1-102.1 185-193.6C399.9 193.1 410.9 181.7 419.6 168.6z"></path></svg></a>
<a href="https://instagram.com/" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;border:0;width:36px;height:36px;padding:0;margin:3px;color:#cce0d7;" target="_blank"><svg class="niftybutton-instagram" data-name="Instagram" data-tag="ins" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="display:block;fill:currentColor" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<path d="M256 109.3c47.8 0 53.4 0.2 72.3 1 17.4 0.8 26.9 3.7 33.2 6.2 8.4 3.2 14.3 7.1 20.6 13.4 6.3 6.3 10.1 12.2 13.4 20.6 2.5 6.3 5.4 15.8 6.2 33.2 0.9 18.9 1 24.5 1 72.3s-0.2 53.4-1 72.3c-0.8 17.4-3.7 26.9-6.2 33.2 -3.2 8.4-7.1 14.3-13.4 20.6 -6.3 6.3-12.2 10.1-20.6 13.4 -6.3 2.5-15.8 5.4-33.2 6.2 -18.9 0.9-24.5 1-72.3 1s-53.4-0.2-72.3-1c-17.4-0.8-26.9-3.7-33.2-6.2 -8.4-3.2-14.3-7.1-20.6-13.4 -6.3-6.3-10.1-12.2-13.4-20.6 -2.5-6.3-5.4-15.8-6.2-33.2 -0.9-18.9-1-24.5-1-72.3s0.2-53.4 1-72.3c0.8-17.4 3.7-26.9 6.2-33.2 3.2-8.4 7.1-14.3 13.4-20.6 6.3-6.3 12.2-10.1 20.6-13.4 6.3-2.5 15.8-5.4 33.2-6.2C202.6 109.5 208.2 109.3 256 109.3M256 77.1c-48.6 0-54.7 0.2-73.8 1.1 -19 0.9-32.1 3.9-43.4 8.3 -11.8 4.6-21.7 10.7-31.7 20.6 -9.9 9.9-16.1 19.9-20.6 31.7 -4.4 11.4-7.4 24.4-8.3 43.4 -0.9 19.1-1.1 25.2-1.1 73.8 0 48.6 0.2 54.7 1.1 73.8 0.9 19 3.9 32.1 8.3 43.4 4.6 11.8 10.7 21.7 20.6 31.7 9.9 9.9 19.9 16.1 31.7 20.6 11.4 4.4 24.4 7.4 43.4 8.3 19.1 0.9 25.2 1.1 73.8 1.1s54.7-0.2 73.8-1.1c19-0.9 32.1-3.9 43.4-8.3 11.8-4.6 21.7-10.7 31.7-20.6 9.9-9.9 16.1-19.9 20.6-31.7 4.4-11.4 7.4-24.4 8.3-43.4 0.9-19.1 1.1-25.2 1.1-73.8s-0.2-54.7-1.1-73.8c-0.9-19-3.9-32.1-8.3-43.4 -4.6-11.8-10.7-21.7-20.6-31.7 -9.9-9.9-19.9-16.1-31.7-20.6 -11.4-4.4-24.4-7.4-43.4-8.3C310.7 77.3 304.6 77.1 256 77.1L256 77.1z"></path>
<path d="M256 164.1c-50.7 0-91.9 41.1-91.9 91.9s41.1 91.9 91.9 91.9 91.9-41.1 91.9-91.9S306.7 164.1 256 164.1zM256 315.6c-32.9 0-59.6-26.7-59.6-59.6s26.7-59.6 59.6-59.6 59.6 26.7 59.6 59.6S288.9 315.6 256 315.6z"></path>
<circle cx="351.5" cy="160.5" r="21.5"></circle></svg>
</a>

</div>
```